# Attribute-based constraints being ignored in Entity Framework Core 8 migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I'm adding the following `Limit` column to a database table `MyTable` via a property in an entity class in a C#, .NET 8, Entity Framework Core 8 code-first application:

```
public int Limit { get; set; }
```

I want the default value for this column to be 2 and to constrain the value to the range [1, 5]. I've tried both

```
[Range(1, 5)]
public int Limit { get; set; } = 2;
```

and

```
[Range(1, 5)]
[DefaultValue(2)]
public int Limit { get; set; }
```

but when I run the Entity Framework Core migration, I get this:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "Limit",
    table: "MyTable",
    type: "int",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0);
```

with default value 0 and no range constraint.

I tried the `OnModelCreating` approach in the database context:

```
MyTable.Property(item => item.Limit).HasDefaultValue(2);
MyTable.ToTable(item => item.HasCheckConstraint("CK_MyTable_Range", "Limit >= 1 AND Limit <= 5"));
```

and got the expected results:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "Limit",
    table: "MyTable",
    type: "int",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 2);

migrationBuilder.AddCheckConstraint(
    name: "CK_MyTable_Range",
    table: "MyTable",
    sql: "Limit >= 1 AND Limit <= 5");
```

So I have *a* solution but I'd like to know why the attribute-based approach isn't working.